# How can I structure this nested mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web form with multiple fields that may or may not be filled out by a user searching for data. The idea is that the user is searching for data between 2 or more parameters. E.G:

- stock price 1 and stock price 2
- market cap 1 and market cap 2 other
- parameter 1 and other parameter 2
  ...

Now the user may choose and combination of these (or all of them) to identify what they are looking for. All of my data is stored in one table. Now I can take any one of these sets of parameters and do a

`"SELECT * FROM tbl_blah WHERE price BETWEEN stockp1 and stockp2"`

which of course works fine.

But things get tricky when I have to nest multiple "WHERE x BETWEEN $1 and $2" type scenarios. I'm not even sure if this is the best approach. I've searched around but I just don't 'get' the statement structure I should be using.

Comment: you are trying to figure out what is the best option of searching when the user selects multiple search criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use multiple between in query.

example :

```
 SELECT *  FROM Chart_Of_Accounts
  WHERE (price BETWEEN '$stockp1' AND '$stockp2') 
  OR (marketcap BETWEEN '$cap1' AND '$cap2') 
  OR (anotherparam BETWEEN '$param1' AND '$param2');
```

Hope its helpful!

Comment: you can use AND in place of OR according to what your required output is.

Comment: I've just tried this with "AND" instead and that's working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically create a query based on what user fills data in.

so, it would be something like this,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_blah WHERE";
if(isset['price'])
$query =  $query + "price BETWEEN stockp1 and stockp2";
if(isset['parameter2'])
$query =  $query + " AND parameter2 BETWEEN stockp3 and stockp4";
```

Now trick here is to check if u need AND or WHERE.